# DataFrame from string that look like table

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have problem with creating DataFrame from string that look like table. Exactly,  I want to create same table as my data.This is my data, and below is my code:

```
                                                          0 2017   IX 2018   X 2018    X 2018   X 2018
                                                                                             0 2017       IX 2018                                    0 2017   IX 2018

    UKUPNO                                               1.053    1.075         1.093        103,8        101,7         1.633    1.669     1.701      104,2    101,9
A   Poljoprivreda, šumarstvo i ribolov                     907      888           925        102,0        104,2         1.394    1.356     1.420      101,9    104,7
B   Vađenje ruda i kamena                                  913      919           839         91,9         91,3         1.395    1.406     1.297       93,0     92,2
C   Prerađivačka industrija                                769      764           775        100,8        101,4         1.176    1.169     1.187      100,9    101,5
D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje                          1.574    1.570         1.647        104,6        104,9         2.459    2.455     2.579      104,9    105,1
    električnom energijom, plinom,
    parom i klimatizacija
E   Snabdijevanje vodom; uklanjanje                        956        973         954         99,8          98,0        1.462    1.491     1.462      100,0     98,1
    otpadnih voda, upravljanje otpadom


TESTDATA = io.StringIO(''' ''')
   df=pd.read_csv(TESTDATA,sep='delimiter',header=None,engine='python')
```

When I read my code, I get this DataFrame

```
0   Prosječna neto plaća ...
1   u KM ...
2   Index Index ...
3   0 2017 IX 2018 X 2018 X 2018 ...
4   0 2017 IX 2018 ...
5   UKUPNO ...
6   A Poljoprivreda, šumarstvo i ribolov ...
7   B Vađenje ruda i kamena ...
8   C Prerađivačka industrija ...
9   D Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje ...
10  električnom energijom, plinom,
```

Comment: `sep='delimiter'` is looking to use the word `'delimiter'` as the separator for fields. Do you know the separator of your file?

Comment: i get this error:Expected 6 fields in line 8, saw 20. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: I have tab delimited text file.

Comment: Using `sep='\t'` does not work?

Comment: It works but I get DataFrame which I don't want:0   Prosječna neto plaća ...
1   u KM ...
2   Index Index ...
3   0 2017 IX 2018 X 2018 X 2018 ...

Comment: I just want to get this data which I already have in table, if I am clear.